# Mac resolution/display randomly changed

Tags: catalina, resolution

So i have a Macbook Pro 2015 15" default of resolution 2880 x 1800 running Catalina, I recently turned it on and either my resolution has been changed or my scaling zoom ( icons, text size etc ) has been altered. I'm 100% that I haven't made these changes myself, nor has anyone else in terms of physically accessing my mac.

Wondering whether this is a common issue or some form of malware/virus?

I've ran Malwarebytes and various other tools to try detect an infection, nothing was detected.

Comment: If it continues to happen it is *possible* that there is something in the video card itself that is failing. EG repair/replace the video card or motherboard.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you reset your NVRAM. This chip stores information on screen resolution and can often become corrupted. You can reset it by starting your Mac while holding down <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>opt</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> . You should hear the Mac chime, restart and chime a second time. Then you can release the keys you are holding. More info [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063).

Comment: I can go that, and I don't see how it can hurt, but if it is choosing resolutions inconsistently it's hard to see how that could be persistently stored in NVRAM.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem with an external monitor, and what worked for me was while the Mac was on and connected to the external monitors, I unplugged the misbehaving monitor from the Mac, waited for about 30 seconds, replugged the misbehaving monitor back into the Mac, waited for about 30 seconds, then opened up the Mac's Settings > Display and selected the misbehaving monitor, and found that the resolution options choices were back to normal and chose the appropriate resolution again, which made the display normal again.